# Gremlin bindings methods support

Tags: python, gremlin

In gremlin docs they describe the use of bindings to reduce the overhead of compilation.

```
g.V(('id',1)).out('created').name.toList()
```

I tried to do the same on has method, but it didn't work

```
g.V().has('some_attribute', 'x', 'some_value')
```

Which methods can be improved using bindings? Can bindings be used on other methods as well besides V()?

Comment: The example shown is using the Gremlin-Python GLV. Folks should be aware that the bindings syntax varies slightly depending on the programming language you're using, i.e. Groovy vs Python vs JavaScript.

Comment: yes, I meant in Python - after lots of googling and tries I've managed to convert has method as well using tuple convension. Following the example it's g.V().has('some_attribute', ('x', 'some_value')).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bindings will work on any script you pass to Gremlin Server. In your examples though I don't see where those scripts would make use of bindings at all. Your first example doesn't appear to look valid. It should be something like:

```
g.V(x).out('created').values('name')
```

where "x" is a binding passed on the request with a value of "1".

Your second example should be something like:

```
g.V().has('name', x)
```

where "x" is a binding passed on the request with the value to match for the 'name' property. I'm just making that last one up as I didn't understand the original traversal too well and what you wanted parameterized.